How can I make a video playlist?
I have a group of 16 video "chapters" on one subject varying from 5 - 15 minutes long. I don't want to make them into one movie because I want to be able to play them in different combinations. Is there a way or a utility I can use to cue them in a kind of video slideshow which will play them sequentially without combining them into a monster file?

Welcome to Ask Different. Can we assume you are on macOS? Feel free to edit more details in your question if no answers make the correct guess on the requirements or your setup.

I would start with VLC since it support chapters and also lets you bookmark and play arbitrary parts of one large video.
If you absolutely need to keep them separate, try a playlist in VLC.
